# Visualizing html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

This may be off topic but I'm not sure where else to go with this question.  I'm just getting started with HTML5 canvas element and all of the incredibly powerful things it can do.  I was hoping someone could offer some advise.  When working with custom paths and bezier curves, what is the easiest/best way to visualize where the points belong on the canvas to achieve a desired effect.  Right now it feels like I'm just guessing plotting points in any place hoping to end up with the right angle/shape that I want.

To be more specific I want to create a shape that will act as an image mask, and will later need to animate this shape.  Much like this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jimrhoskins/dDUC3/1/ (someone else's work) but since I can't see where the picture is on the canvas or where any of the points are, I'm really just guessing at the approximate shape I need to make.  I'm just wondering if there's a better way, or some function in javascript that can map the location of an image and give me at least a better place to start.

Here is what I know/have tried already

```
// Grab the Canvas and Drawing Context
    var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');



// Create an image element
   var img = document.createElement('IMG');

// When the image is loaded, draw it
img.onload = function () {

// Save the state, so we can undo the clipping
    context.save();


// Create a shape, of some sort
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(somex, somey);
    context.bezierCurveTo(somexstart, someystart, somexcontrol, someycontro, somexend, someyend);
    context.arcTo(somecoordinates);
    context.closePath();
// Clip to the current path
    context.clip();


    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

// Undo the clipping
    context.restore();
}

// Specify the src to load the image
img.src = "url";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about opening the image in an SVG editor. Drawing a path on a layer above the image. Then open the SVG and copy the coordinates?

Comment: Thanks for the advice,  I'll give that a shot.  Not sure why I didn't do that in the first place

Answer (score 0):

Try an [SVG Editor](http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/editor/svg-editor.html). You can get the points there. You can add images too. SVG [animation](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-animate-festive-svg-icons-with-css--webdesign-17658) is used nowadays as well. If you have Adobe Illustrator, it will be easier to draw there and just save it as SVG.